# Location of child object

Tags: python, scripting, matrix

I have a child object **c** parented to another object **p**.

If now I check `c.location` from python console it's totally different than the one shown in the item tab of the side panel. The side panel shows the value that corresponds to the object location as seen in the viewport. But I had the understanding that this is also the value of `c.location`.

The question is how is the actual value in the viewport (the one shown on the item tab) is related to `c.location`

Edit:
Please ignore this post. The difference was because of the system unit. (See comments)

Comment: i have object c.location = (-1,0,0) then i parent it to p. the location is still the same in side panel and traced in python console. so i'm not sure what you mean. can you post some screenshots to clarify your problem?

Comment: You are right, I had set up my system to use imperial units. So the location in the side panel was in feet and in the console it was metric. But they are the same after conversion.